# Truncate some rows in table SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, delete-row

I have a table named 'dbo.Employees' with some records inside. I want to perform truncate bottom 50 rows. How could I do this in the studio?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Emplyees];
```

The code above truncates the whole table.

Comment: Use `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Great Thanks Felix Pamittan. Solved it!